# A brief guide to extensions, namespaces and assemblies in V1 of Reactive Extensions (Rx)

Tags: .net, system.reactive

Exploring the latest release of Reactive Extensions, I discover that the different types and extension methods have been split across namespaces and assemblies.

I know that I can go looking one by one on MSDN, but what I'd like is a brief overview of the logic of this segregation (I don't mean a *justification*, but *if you're looking for this, try here first*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assemblies

- `System.Reactive.dll` - The core APIs
- `System.Reactive.Providers.dll` - IQbservable interfaces and implementation over objects
- `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms.dll` - Schedulers and integration for WinForms
- `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading.dll` - Schedulers and integration for WPF/Silverlight
- `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing.dll` - Classes for testing Rx-  Mocks, Recorders, Virtual schedulers, etc

### Namespaces

- `System.Reactive.Concurrency` - Schedulers
- `System.Reactive.Disposables` - Classes for creating and using disposables. (I was sad to see these classes moved into the Rx specific namespace, as they are generally useful)
- `System.Reactive.Joins` - Join matching patterns
- `System.Reactive.Linq` - Combinators and extension methods on IObservable and IQbservable. This is the main namespace for most consumers
- `System.Reactive.Subjects` - Subject implement both IObservable and IObserver and have state
- `System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks` - Interop to the TPL